# Set local time in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, date-time

I need to set the local time on my Windows XP machine to same as the time in my server which is Windows 2003 server. Is there a command to set that in command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

From `net help time`:

> NET TIME
>
> `[\\computername | /DOMAIN[:domainname] | /RTSDOMAIN[:domainname]] [/SET]`
>
> NET TIME synchronizes the computer's clock with that of another computer or domain, or displays the time for a computer or domain. When used without options on a Windows Server domain, it displays the current date and time at the computer designated as the time server for the domain.
>
> `\\computername` — Is the name of the computer you want to check or synchronize with.
>
> `/DOMAIN[:domainname]` — Specifies to synchronize the time from the Primary Domain Controller of domainname.
>
> `/RTSDOMAIN[:domainname]` — Specifies to synchronize with a Reliable Time Server from domainname.
>
> `/SET` — Synchronizes the computer's time with the time on the specified computer or domain.

(Sorry, it's from Windows 7, but the general workings and options are the same for XP.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a permanent solution, you should set up a time server on the server.

See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042).